# How to get quaternion values based on a coordinate system for a different coordinate system?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions, coordinate-systems

I have the quaternion values from a particular coordinate system and I need to map that to Unity's coordinate system (which uses left hand coordinate system).  Using (x, y, z) is the axis of Unity's coordinate system, I would like to get quaternion for Unity's coordinate system from a quaternion value that is generated using coordinate system (y, -x, -z) (See below)

How do I calculate the new quaternion values based on the new coordinate system that will still allow the object to orient correctly (so what faces up remains faces up in the new system)?

[image]

Comment: By looking at values it looks like simple 90 degree rotation around z axis, quaternion class should provide axis-angle constructor, which can be used to do that rotation with params: 90 (-90 I'm not sure) angle, (0,0,1) axis

Comment: @Rychu I have attached a screenshot to better illustrate.  z-axis is inverted as well.

Comment: In that case it's more problematic - it's a rotation and flip, which I don't think is possible to represent as just a rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's my proposition - as there's a rotation and flip, and if I understood correctly you just need to present object exported from some application in unity, I'd do the following:

For every object you need to 'fix' set transform to 90 (or -90, I'm never sure about the direction) rotation around Z axis and scale (1, 1, -1). If you want to be able easily apply more, you could encapsulate those objects in empty GameObject (with bare transform) for each and apply needed transformations to those gameObjects.